# Is the HTML form the only way to make a POST request without using JS?

Tags: html, http, post

As far as I know, without using JavaScript (or other tools like cURL), I can only make GET and POST requests using a Browser. I can make a GET by accessing the URL, but is the HTML form the only way to make a POST request?

Comment: What technology are you asking about? Other programming languages and frameworks allow you to make POST requests... This question is unclear and you are getting a lot of guesses as to answers as a result.

Answer (score 1):

You can perform HTTP requests from any kind using developer tools or extensions on most browsers. Their is also softwares that helps you creating HTTP requests like [insomnia](https://insomnia.rest/) or [postman](https://www.getpostman.com/).

Comment: I would think those would be included in "other tools like cURL"...

Comment: Yup, curl and wget can do the job too

Comment: But the OP asked for solutions "without using JavaScript (or other tools like cURL)", and this answer says, you can use these other tools like cURL.

Comment: What I understood is that OP doesn't want to write any JavaScript but not that he doesn't want to use already-made applications using JavaScript

Answer (score 0):

Postman can also make POST and GET request when testing APIs. You can download on windows, Mac and Linux.

Comment: I would think that Postman would be included in "other tools like cURL"...

Answer (score 0):

If you're *only* using HTML to make a POST request, then yes, an HTML form is the only way to achieve that. But if you're just trying to test POST requests then software like @D. Nathanael mentioned would do the trick.